# Nextcloud client

Tags: nextcloud

I have a Pi 4 with Open Media Vault (mainly for smb and nfs services) with external drives to share files on the local network.

How can I install the NextCloud client to synchronise the files on the Raspberry Pi with my cloud storage?

I have seen many posts about installing the NextCloud server, not much about the client.

Comment: https://nextcloud.com/install/#install-clients or add the repository: https://launchpad.net/~nextcloud-devs/+archive/ubuntu/client